# Makefile:1: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Stop. Error in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, compilation

I am currently working on a problem for uni in a Ubuntu terminal using VMware Player. They have supplied me with the Makefile necessary to use with the code I have been tasked to write so I can't show the code for it. However since it was supplied by them it should work without issue and has for most other people. However, when I attempt to use it I receive the error:

Makefile:1: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.

I ran the following command in the Makefile to try to fix it as it is meant to substitute all the lines that begin with 1 or more spaces with a tab but I still got the error.

```
:%s/^[ ]\+/^I/
```

I asked on the uni forum about it and they told me to check if the text editor expands tabs into spaces as make requires actual tabs but I am unsure of how to do this. So how can I check to see if it is in fact the text editor expanding tabs to spaces and how would I change that if it is the problem, or is there another way to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue--I was getting this error after running that command and thoroughly checking for inserted spaces. The issue ended up being my text editor: I was using Sublime Text 2. I pulled the Makefile up with vim, replaced the "tabs" with tabs in vim, and it made successfully.